# Need help to understand on WebRTC error: Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint

Tags: webrtc, pbx

I have a self-hosted PBX application which I have trouble with it webRTC trunk. This error happened when upgrading to its latest major version. Tbh, i'm dont have much experience with webRTC trunk and even after i do reading online on how it work, i only understood some of it concept and still not able to pinpoint where is the error, either from my side or because of the application itself. So my main purpose of this question is to understand more on the error since i didnt get much from their support team for this issue.

The idea of this WebRTC trunk is to have a button resides on our company website and the outside world can click that button to reach our pbx and route to any intended recipient. bellow is the part of log that contain error which i capture using webrtc-internal in Chrome. When i click button call, it able to ring the number in pbx but when i answer, the calls didnt connect between 2 parties. and usually when it works, the call button will turn red from original green but this attempt doesnt turn the button to red. it stay on green.

note:

- the bold section is the error found
- 126.222.227.90 - public ip of the pbx
- 172.19.80.1 - local ip for hyper V Virtual Ethernet Adapter
- 192.168.100.40 - host initiated the call from webRTC call button.

```
setLocalDescriptionOnSuccess
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
signalingstatechange
have-local-offer
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
transceiverModified [0], audio
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
icegatheringstatechange
gathering
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: host)
sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:1340996792 1 udp 2122260223 172.19.80.1 49643 typ host generation 0 ufrag CVXb network-id 1
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: host)
sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:2100252196 1 udp 2122194687 192.168.100.40 49644 typ host generation 0 ufrag CVXb network-id 2
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
setRemoteDescription (type: "answer", 2 sections)
Copy description to clipboard
v=0 (5 more lines)
o=- 9024379899958319145 2 IN IP4 126.222.227.90
s=-
c=IN IP4 126.222.227.90
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
m=audio 59342 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 0 8 9 126 110 (10 more lines) mid=0
a=mid:0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:126 0-15
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=fmtp:110 0-15
a=rtcp-mux
a=sendrecv
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
**setRemoteDescriptionOnFailure**
Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint.
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: srflx)
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
**addIceCandidateFailed**
sdpMid: , sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:706533 1 udp 366268 126.222.227.90 59342 typ host generation 0 ufrag 
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: host)
2/7/2024, 10:35:53 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: host)
2/7/2024, 10:36:04 AM   
setRemoteDescription (type: "answer", 2 sections)
2/7/2024, 10:36:04 AM   
setRemoteDescriptionOnFailure
Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called with SDP without DTLS fingerprint.
2/7/2024, 10:36:04 AM   
addIceCandidateFailed
sdpMid: , sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:165981 1 udp 815953 126.222.227.90 59342 typ host generation 0 ufrag 
2/7/2024, 10:36:24 AM   
setLocalDescription (munged) (type: "offer", 2 sections)
2/7/2024, 10:36:24 AM   
signalingstatechange
2/7/2024, 10:36:24 AM   
iceconnectionstatechange
2/7/2024, 10:36:24 AM   
connectionstatechange
```

i tried to downgrade the current major version to previous one major version (the most stable version and the one we provided to our client) since the previous version dont have this issue. the feature works fine. i also tried to recreate the similar type of trunk but still got the same error.